# Slash and backslash in sed

Tags: bash, sed, quoting

I want to use `sed` to change a slash into a backslash and a slash, i.e. `/` -> `\/`. But it does not work. Here a small example:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST=/etc/hallo
echo $TEST
echo $TEST | sed "s/hallo/bello/g"
echo $TEST | sed "s/\//\\\//g"
```

The output of the first three lines is as assumed. But the last one does not work. Why? How to correct the last part?

Comment: When in doubt, echo the command: `echo sed "s/\//\\\//g"` -> `sed s/\//\\//g`. Btw you can use something else for sed, like `'s@/@\\/@g'`.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use single quotes for the expression you used:

```
sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

In double quotes, `\` has a special meaning, so you have to backslash it:

```
sed "s/\//\\\\\//g"
```

But it's cleaner to change the delimiter:

```
sed 's=/=\\/=g'
sed "s=/=\\\/=g"
```

Comment: Alternate delimiters are awesome.

Comment: Seem like end-of-line (`$`) and beginning-of-line (`^`) are handled differently, if at all, when using single quotes. What's going on with them?

Comment: @not2qubit: Can you provide an example? `$` might be special in double quotes, but should be OK in single quotes.

Comment: I tried to remove ```\``` from the end of lines with: `cat file.h | sed -zE 's/\\$//g'` and that didn't work. However, without the `$` it worked, but then it also catches stuff in between.

Comment: @not2qubit: Under `-z`, `$` matches at a null byte, not at a newline.

Comment: I was sure to have tried it also without. Can it have something to do with the file character encoding or EOL settings? (I.e. UTF-8 vs ASCII, and `\r` vs `\r\n`?)

Comment: Yes, `$` doesn't match before `\r`.

Comment: More about alternate delimiters: https://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/index.html You can use almost anything char as a delimiter, even spaces!

Answer (score 27):

Try:

```
sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

or using another delimiter to prevent you from escaping slash:

```
sed 's,/,\\/,g'
```